# PrimeFaces 6.0 e 6.1 - Erro no JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, jquery-ui

Ao incluir qualquer componente do Primefaces no corpo do meu HTML, ele levanta esse erro: Uncaught TypeError: N.delegate is not a function.

Vocês sabem o que seria?

O erro esta nessa segunda linha do jquery-plugins gerado pelo Primefaces

```js
 function g(N) {
        var M = "button, .ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next, .ui-datepicker-calendar td a";
        return N.delegate(M, "mouseout", function() {
            y(this).removeClass("ui-state-hover");
            if (this.className.indexOf("ui-datepicker-prev") !== -1) {
                y(this).removeClass("ui-datepicker-prev-hover")
            }
            if (this.className.indexOf("ui-datepicker-next") !== -1) {
                y(this).removeClass("ui-datepicker-next-hover")
            }
        }).delegate(M, "mouseover", function() {
            if (!y.datepicker._isDisabledDatepicker(j.inline ? N.parent()[0] : j.input[0])) {
                y(this).parents(".ui-datepicker-calendar").find("a").removeClass("ui-state-hover");
                y(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
                if (this.className.indexOf("ui-datepicker-prev") !== -1) {
                    y(this).addClass("ui-datepicker-prev-hover")
                }
                if (this.className.indexOf("ui-datepicker-next") !== -1) {
                    y(this).addClass("ui-datepicker-next-hover")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: `N` que está sendo enviado como argumento não possui a função `delegate`. Dê um `console.log` em `N` para ver o que está vindo, talvez esteja `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

A função .delegate() foi descontinuada no JQuery, porém a turma do PrimeFaces utilizou ela na versão 6.1 RC1, mais agora na versão 6.1 RC2, este erro foi corrigido! Mais obirgiado a todos.